# How to handle modal using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

```
<h1 class="modalHeader"> Device Properties of test1234 </h1>

<div class="mainPopContent">
    <ul id="parent" class="tree">
        <li id="child">
            List Index: <span>1</span>
        </li>
        <li id="child">
            Device Type: <span>test 6000</span>

            <li id="child" class="has-children"><i class="js-toggle-icon">+</i>
            Network Mode
            <ul id="parent" style="display: none;">
                <li id="child">
                     Auto
                </li>
                <li id="child">
                    Firmware: <span>1.2.2.43</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**Summary** : When I am clicking on "edit" button pop up modal is opening and from that modal i need to get the following details.

I need to get the `Device Type` and `Firmware` text from the modal using python selenium.

How can i achieve this issue?

Please help me

Stackrace :

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12345/devtools/browser/af75ff22-1e5f-4493-8f56-158910238bf5
Device Type: EM 6000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asif.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::li[2]/li/i[@class='js-toggle-icon']").click()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 385, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::
li[2]/li/i[@class='js-toggle-icon']"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? What have you tried and why did it not work? From your post, I can't see if it is even necessary to use Selenium. Could you share the URL so we can see the page in question ourselves?

Comment: Do you want to extract **Device Type** and **Firmware** as text or the values i.e. **test 6000** and **1.2.2.43**

Comment: Share your current code and describe the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML to extract the text **Device Type** from the modal you can use the following line of code :

```
Device_Type_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::li[2]")))
Device_Type = Device_Type_element.text
```

To click on **Network Mode** you can use the following line of code :

```
Network_Mode = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::li[2]//i[@class='js-toggle-icon']")))
Network_Mode.click()
```

Finally, as per the HTML to extract the text **Firmware** from the modal you have to remove the `style="display: none;"` first and you can use the following line of code :

```
Firmware_webelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::li[2]//ul//following::li[2]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", Firmware_webelement)
Firmware = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainPopContent']/ul[@class='tree' and @id='parent']//following-sibling::li[2]//ul//following::li[2]").text
```

Comment: Firmware is not working...To get text from firm ware i need to click on "Network mode". Here is the html code : I need to click on the Network mode...<li id="child" class="has-children"><i class="js-toggle-icon minus">-</i>
            Network Mode
            <ul id="parent" style="">
                <li id="child">
                     Auto 
                </li>
                <li id="child">
                    Firmware: <span>1.2.2.43</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

Comment: How can i click? Please help me

Comment: Thanks but i want to click on "network mode"..That's my requirement in test case...How to click on "Network mode" Please help me

Comment: It's not working...I need to click on network mode then the text will be visible.It's inside Network mode

Comment: I'm getting this error : Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/

Comment: Pasted the complete error stack trace within the question please.

Comment: Added Please check

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

I like @DebanjanB 's Waits, but that method is WAY more complex than required. This should get you there (try for surgical XPaths, they are less brittle).

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='js-toggle-icon']/..").click()
device_type = find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(), 'Device Type')]/span").text
firmware = find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(), 'Firmware')]/span").text
```

Comment: Works fine if you add time.sleep(5) above your 3 lines  of code.

Comment: @Tola time.sleep is a great way to write slow, expensive test suites. Use Explicit Waits, save yourself and your team time and money.